# Segmentation fault with boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost, segmentation-fault

I just installed boost on my mac. (Installed MacPorts, sudo port install boost)
In XCode I added Header Search Path (/opt/local/include) and Library Search Path (/opt/local/lib) and added libraries into Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries (libboost_filesystem-mt.a, libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib, libboost_system-mt.a, libboost_system-mt.dylib).
Now I trying to build and run this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main() {
    std::string filename;
    std::cin >> filename;
    std::cout << boost::filesystem::exists(filename);

    return 0;
}
```

And with any path typed I got Segmentation Fault: 11 when calling exists().

What i did wrong? Is any mistakes when installing boost?

Comment: Had this exact problem on windows this week when accidentally linking against boost release build libraries, with a debug version of the app (in visual studio 2005). Now I don't know if this goes for osx as well - (I've never experienced this in linux, but in linux my build system is different, and off the bat I cannot say if I ever tried linking release boost libs to debug versions of my software)

Comment: I got the same issue on Ubuntu, could this be the same issue?

Answer (score 4):

I've run in to similar problems in the past when boost isn't built with the same `CXXFLAGS` as your program. Here's a pseudo-complete set of bootstrap instructions.

```sh
# Configure, build, and install boost
./bootstrap.sh \
  --prefix=${PWD}/.local \
  --with-libraries=...,filesystem,...
./b2 \
  -q \
  -d2 \
  -j4 \
  --debug-configuration \
  --disable-filesystem2 \
  --layout=tagged \
  --build-dir=${PWD}/obj \
  cxxflags="-v -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" \
  linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" \
  link=shared \
  threading=multi \
  install
```

The important part there is the `cxxflags` and `linkflags`. In my experience, it's most often because macports compiles without using `-stdlib=libc++` but that's required when using compiling `C++11` code using `-std=c++11`. Common symptoms include random backtraces in gdb that indicate something is a problem with a pointer inside of a particular struct buried deep within a boost library/template.

As you can tell from the above, I build a local copy of boost in to a per-project directory (e.g. `${PWD}/.local`) and then link against the local version during development until it's time to package (at which point I statically link or do something else).

```
# In a GNUmakefile
LOCAL_DIR=${PWD}/.local
INC_DIR=${LOCAL_DIR}/include
LIB_DIR=${LOCAL_DIR}/lib

CPPFLAGS=-I"${INC_DIR}"
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
LDFLAGS=-stdlib=libc++ -L"${LIB_DIR}"

MYPROG_SRCS=myprog.cpp
MYPROG_OBJS=$(MYPROG_SRCS:.cpp=.o)

%.o : %.cpp %.hpp
        ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${CPPFLAGS} -c -o $@ $<

myprog: ${MYPROG_OBJS}
        ${CXX} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ $^ ${LIBS}
```

Bottom line: your `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` need to match between boost and your program.

Comment: It works! But why is -stdlib=libc++ needed when passing c++11? If I look into the file with otool it anyways uses libc++, so what is really different?

Comment: @IceFire Some old versions of clang on macOS use very old libstdc++ headers by default, and those headers predate C++11. To use C++11 library features you need a C++11-capable stdlib, so either newer libstdc++ headers that you install yourself, or just use libc++.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and it seems to work OK - I built your code as follows:

```
$ g++ -Wall -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt boost_filesystem.cpp
```

This is using Xcode 5, and boost 1.51.0 downloaded directly from http://boost.org and installed in `/usr/local`.