# MacOS compile from Mavericks Lion compatible executable

Tags: c, macos, clang, std

Since I updated to Mavericks my C app, compiled in my machine with clang, cannot be executed in Lion machines (yep, there are some people who have not updated). It throws

> Segmentation fault: 11 error

I've read about stdlib option [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19774902/105334) but it seems it only applies to clang++ and not to plain clang. Is there a similar option for clang?  I've searched for `--stdlib=libstdc` in google but all results are for `--stdlib=libstdc++`

Comment: Have you set the deployment target and SDK to 10.8?

Comment: How do you do that? I'm not using xcode just explicit calls to clang as part of a larger, pipelined, build process

Comment: Did you have a chance to check the answer? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Nope, I tried and compiles that way but I wont have access to a non-updated machine till next week

Answer (score 3):

To compile an app for OS X 10.8 (Lion), you have to set the "Deployment Target".
The corresponding command line option for clang is

```
-mmacosx-version-min=10.8
```

You might also want to set the SDK to 10.8, to avoid that any library functions are used that are available only in 10.9:

```
-isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the intent of the question, but Lion is actually 10.7, *Mountain Lion* is 10.8. Obviously, you wouldn't want to set the deployment target to 10.8, if you were targeting Lion (10.7). Both the previous comments and answer are conflicting in that regard.

*Note: I can't comment on them, as I don't have enough rep!