# C++0x compiler support issue

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, cc

Trying to install [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX)on Ubuntu 14.04 but getting stuck with this error

> Error: your compiler does not support C++0x, please update it.

Checked my version of both gcc & g++

> gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-3ubuntu2~14.04.1) 4.9.1
>
> g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.1-3ubuntu2~14.04.1) 4.9.1

Which should be ok for C++0x support.  Also added a symbolic links for cc & c++.  What am I missing here?  Doesn't 4.9.1 support C++0x?

EDIT:

Error occurs when I'm trying to make the app using cmake .. here's what I can find in the CMakeLists.txt

```
# CYGWIN or GCC 4.5.x bug
if(CYGWIN)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++0x")
else()
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
endif()

>include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
check_cxx_compiler_flag("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" CXX0X_SUPPORT)
if(NOT CXX0X_SUPPORT)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Error: your compiler does not support C++0x, please update it.")
endif()
```

Comment: Did you pass `-std=c++11` when you compiled?

Comment: For sure your compiler supports it! How are you compiling?

Comment: actually it's better to use -std=gnu++11, -std=c++11 disables most gnu extensions.

Comment: @EvanDark Therefore it is better to use `-std=c++11`.

Comment: it's when I'm running cmake .. check out the edit above

Comment: Try replacing `std=c++0x` with `std=c++11`

Comment: @ben-voigt no luck replacing std=c++0x with std=c++11 .. looks like it has more to do with the check_cxx_compiler_flag function

Comment: it can fail due to other invalid CXX flags (not related to -std), what are they? can you `message( STATUS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")` ?

Comment: @piotr-s -Wall -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 .. thinking about perhaps just disabling the check

Comment: `-stdlib=libc++` -> `-stdlib=libstdc++` ?

Comment: nope didn't work .. just going to remove the check and see if I can get around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so it looks like ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} was including

> -stdlib=libc++

According to this post [When is it necessary to use use the flag -stdlib=libstdc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774778/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-use-the-flag-stdlib-libstdc) it's not necessary, so removed it seemed to solve the issue