# Simple ObjC program falling to freeze

Tags: objective-c

Why ObjC program getting stuck?
I'm newbie in ObjC and trying to compile it on Linux system by command:

gcc $(gnustep-config --objc-flags) *.m $(gnustep-config --base-libs)

Here the code:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        Rect * r = [[Rect alloc]initWithWidth:30 height:50];
        NSLog(@"%f", [r height]);

        [pool drain];
        return 0;
}

//=====
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Rect : NSObject <NSCopying> {
}

@property double width;
@property double height;

- (Rect *) initWithWidth:(double)w
                  height:(double)h;
- (double) height;
//...

//=====
@implementation Rect
- (Rect *) initWithWidth:(double)w
                  height:(double)h
{
    self.width = w;
    self.height = h;
    return [super init];
}

- (double) height
{
    return self.height;
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a infinite recursive loop when you call `return self.height;` change that line to `return _height;` and it should work. You can also remove the `- (double) height;` from the header file since your property declaration generates a setter `- (void)setHeight:(double)height;` and a getter `- (double)height;` automatically. You should also probably remove the getter from your implementation since its already generated with the property declaration.

Comment: Thanks. I removed setterd and getters and got such error:  *rectangle.m:29:1: warning: incomplete implementation of class ‘Rect’  
rectangle.m:29:1: warning: method definition for ‘-setWidth:’ not found  
rectangle.m:29:1: warning: method definition for ‘-width’ not found  
rectangle.m:29:1: warning: method definition for ‘-setHeight:’ not found
rectangle.m:29:1: warning: method definition for ‘-height’ not found*

Comment: Since you are using gcc I'm not sure, whether it supports automatic accessor synthesize. Did you try to add `@synthesize height, width;` at the beginning of the implementation? However, you can use clang for compiling.

Comment: Does the program compile and run ok?

Comment: @PeterSegerblom no. I added ```@synthesize``` directive (just below under ```@implementation```), removed all setters and getters and anyway got errors about incomplete class declaration.   Moreover I haven't used clang with other languages due to this bug with my distro: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333823). I'll try to workaround this and will send more info. Thanks for your help, guys!