# How to fix "fatal error: 'iostream' file not found" after upgrading to Xcode 10.1

Tags: c++, include, iostream, clang++, xcode10

This error has only appeared for me since updating Xcode (and to MacOS Mojave 10.14). Something similar happened with `#include <Python>`, which I fixed by instead using #include "python2.7/Python.h".

There is a similar error discussed in [Clang doesn't see basic headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333823/clang-doesnt-see-basic-headers). When I try

`clang++ -stdlib=libc++ PyTrans.cpp -o  -v`

I get

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`.

The full error:

```
warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-std=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
```

`/Users/joe/Documents/Research/EkpPyTransportDist/PyTransport/PyTrans/PyTrans.cpp:20:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
include <iostream>
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Any help would be greatly appreciated; I am very new to C++.

Edit: Spacing within brackets.

Comment: Get rid of the spaces in your include. Make it `#include <iostream>` It's actually looking for a " iostream " file meaning with a space before and after the iostream.

Comment: Having spaces inside include directive is erroneous.

Comment: I got this error because I tried to use `/usr/bin/cpp` instead of `/usr/bin/clang++` to compile a C++ file.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the error message carefully, you'll see that it says "pass `-std=libc++` on the command line." If you re-read what you actually wrote, it says `-stdlib=libc++`. Remove the extra `lib` you have in there and it should work just fine.

Also, as others have commented on your post, you should remove the spaces in your include directives: `#include <iostream>`

Comment: Using `clang++ -stdlib=libc++ PyTrans.cpp -o  -v` gives `error: invalid value 'libc++' in '-std=libc++'`, but then gives a few suggestions. I tried one of them, `clang++ -std=c++17 PyTrans.cpp -o  -v`, which still gives the linker issue. And I did do the correct spacing within the brackets; I added the space when posting here since the word "iostream" would not appear otherwise.

Comment: @J.Wraga Ah, sorry. I got those two flags mixed up. In that case, it sounds like something to do with your include path is messed up. I would consider reinstalling XCode or the command line utilities. Also, the `.o` flag is not useful on its own, though I doubt that that has anything to do with your error. I'm not sure I can help more than that, unfortunately :(