# NVIDIA's HPCCM installed clang-15 cant find omp.h

Tags: docker, clang

Im using [NVIDIA's HPC-Container-Maker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/hpc-container-maker) to build [minivite](https://github.com/ECP-ExaGraph/miniVite) with clang-15 in a docker container. The HPCCM recipe is at the end of this post and it uses the llvm and openmpi building blocks.

After running:

```
hpccm --recipe ./recipe.py --format docker > Dockerfile
docker build -t test .
```

I get the error:

```
[19/19] RUN cd minivite &&     make:                                                                                                                                         
#0 0.293 mpicxx -std=c++11 -g -O3 -fopenmp -DPRINT_DIST_STATS  -c -o main.o main.cpp                                                                                            
#0 0.650 main.cpp:53:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found                                                                                                                    
#0 0.650 #include <omp.h>
#0 0.650          ^~~~~~~
#0 0.884 1 error generated.
#0 0.891 make: *** [Makefile:23: main.o] Error 1
```

By removing the compilation step from the recipe and entering the container, i install locate and do:

```
locate /omp.h
```

and get:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include/omp.h
/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/omp.h
```

So it seems it exists for some compilers, but not for clang-15. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333823/clang-doesnt-see-basic-headers), but isnt hpccm tool supposed to take care of that for me? Especially the openmi=True flag in llvm() building block. It seems fishy to bypass the framework and manually install a compiler just to fix a bug...
Am i doing something wrong?

OBS: HPCCM recipe:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import hpccm

#Ubuntu 22.04 base image
Stage0 += baseimage(image='ubuntu:22.04')
Stage0 += gnu()

#Clang version 15...
compiler = llvm(version="15")
Stage0 += compiler

#Default version value is 4.0.5. OpenMPI supports 
Stage0 += ofed()
Stage0 += gdrcopy()
Stage0 += knem()
Stage0 += xpmem()
Stage0 += ucx(cuda=False, repository='https://github.com/openucx/ucx.git', branch="v1.14.1")
Stage0 += openmpi(cuda=False, infiniband=False, toolchain=compiler.toolchain, ucx=True)

Stage0 += apt_get(ospackages=['make', 'wget', 'tar', 'libomp-dev'])
Stage0 += shell(commands=['wget https://github.com/ECP-ExaGraph/miniVite/archive/refs/tags/v1.2.tar.gz; tar -xzvf v1.2.tar.gz; mv miniVite-1.2/ minivite'])
Stage0 += copy(src="Makefile", dest="/minivite")
Stage0 += shell(commands=['cd minivite', 'make'])
```