# Error in compiling CUDA code with clang++

Tags: cuda, llvm, clang++

I am trying to compile cuda (simple hello_world program) code with clang to generate its LLVM IR and subsequently get its call graph using the following command.

```
clang++-13 hello_world.cu --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_75 -S -emit-llvm -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart_static -pthread
```

But I am getting the following error messages :

```
clang: warning: CUDA version is newer than the latest partially supported version 11.8 [-Wunknown-cuda-version]
clang: warning: -lcudart_static: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16/include/__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:41:
/usr/lib/llvm-16/lib/clang/16/include/cuda_wrappers/cmath:27:15: fatal error: 'cmath' file not found
#include_next <cmath>
              ^~~~~~~
1 error generated when compiling for host.
```

I am running code on a `Turing` Architecture machine have the following clang and CUDA:

```
Ubuntu clang version 16.0.6 (++20230710042046+7cbf1a259152-1~exp1~20230710162136.105)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

CUDA Version: 12.2
```

Please find the link to code below :
[Vector Addition](https://pastebin.com/EfkFfH8V)

I also tried running the code on `cuda version 11.7` using `clang++-14` and got the following error messages :

```
clang++-14 vector-addition.cu --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_75 -S -emit-llvm -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart_static -pthread
clang: warning: -lcudart_static: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
In file included from <built-in>:1:
/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.6/include/__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:41:10: fatal error: 'cmath' file not found
 #include <cmath>
          ^~~~~~~
 1 error generated when compiling for host.
```

Can somebody please help me on how to resolve the error?

P.S.: Adding the flag -stdlib=libc++ solved the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26333823/681865

Comment: @talonmies thank you for the answer it worked for me.