# CLion GNU STL Renderers

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, cmake, clion

I am trying to debug a C++ program that uses std::map.
In this post http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/05/debug-clion/ it says that they support GNU STL Renderers if you include -stdlib=libstdc++ in the CMake file, however I get an error when building.

```
c++: error: unrecognized command line option '--stdlib=libstdc++'
```

Here is my CMake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
```

project(lint)

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 --stdlib=libstdc++")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(lint ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Here is my main.cpp

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    list<map<string, int>*>* sint3 = new list<map<string,int>*>;
    sint3->push_front(new map<string,int>);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I get GNU STL Renderers to work like their announcement said?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this extra dash:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libstdc++")
//                                                  ^^^
```

One dash goes a long way in the command line!

Also, look closely at the linked article:

> This feature works in GCC, and in the case of Clang it works for libstdc++ only.

From what I conclude that with g++, there is no need to append this option, the renderers should work out of the box.

Edit: the obligatory [SO question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774778/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-use-the-flag-stdlib-libstdc).

Comment: I still get the same error
    c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libstdc++'

Comment: Try `-stdlib=libc++` and see my comment under the question.

Comment: That didn't work and the link you posted has to do with MacOSX right? I am on windows using Cygwin.

Comment: @McDonnas yes the link is for Linux and MacOSX, but more precisely it is for g++ and clang++, which compiler and compiler version are you using?

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.93 (this seems like the latest too me)

Comment: Alright, this is not the latest, the current branch is 5, but still: try my second suggestion and remove the option we're discussing altogether from CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I have done that, however I am still not able to view any of the details of std::map, or any other STL containers

Comment: Is your build a debug build? `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE debug)` or `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug`

Comment: Ya that doesn't work either, it still doesn't show me the internals of any STL.