# Why libstdc++ doesn't recognize std::vector::cbegin whereas libc++ does?

Tags: c++, clang, libstdc++

Here is a toy C++ file named `cbegin.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> toto;
    auto first = toto.cbegin();

    return 0;
}
```

I want to compile it with this command:

```
clang -x c++ -arch i386 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -lstdc++ cbegin.cpp -o cbegin
```

But I get this error:

```
cbegin.cpp:7:20: error: no member named 'cbegin' in 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >'
        auto first = toto.cbegin();
```

If I use `libc++`, it works well:

```
clang -x c++ -arch i386 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -lstdc++ cbegin.cpp -o cbegin
```

Why `libstdc++` doesn't recognize `std::vector::cbegin`? I can't move to `libc++` in my project because I have external dependencies compiled with `libstdc++`.

Comment: Does your libstdc++ support c++11?

Comment: this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774778/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-use-the-flag-stdlib-libstd

Comment: @juanchopanza How can I check that?

Comment: @Pierre Include the header <iterator>

Comment: [What version of libstdc++ do you have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354636/how-do-you-find-what-version-of-libstdc-library-is-installed-on-your-linux-mac)?

Comment: `-arch i386` - *really*? That's some seriously *old* hardware you (seem to) need to support. If you don't *actually* need to support such old hardware, then please let your compiler optimize for newer hardware. It'll make a significant difference in performance. You are currently restraining your compiler *significantly*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's the project I'm working on.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I did it but it changed nothing. What's the point?

Comment: Did you read the link that bracco23 provided?  It explains the difference between libc++ and libstd++.

Comment: @Eljay It said that `libstdc++` doesn't support C++11. Should I understand there is no ways to use `std::vector::cbegin` with it?

Comment: @Pierre It looks like so apparently.