# fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, homebrew, fatal-error

I am getting the following error when I try to execute c++ code

```
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_3/include/c++/10.2.0/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_3/include/c++/10.2.0/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_3/include/c++/10.2.0/ios:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_3/include/c++/10.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_3/include/c++/10.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_3/include/c++/10.2.0/cwchar:44:10: fatal error: wchar.h: No such file or directory
   44 | #include <wchar.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I am using gcc10 on MacOS Big Sur 11.2
The compiler was working fine till I updated homebrew or updated to Big Sur 11.2.
Running brew cleanup could've also broken it.
I have tried unlinking and linking gcc again but that had no effect.
What can I do to fix this error? Would it be better to delete and reinstall gcc?

Comment: You didn't specified stdlib for gcc. Bet they changed default locations for shared libs gcc wanted to resolve to. Something like stdlib. [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774778/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-the-flag-stdlib-libstdc)

Comment: No, you're getting that error when you're *compiling* C++ code. Please update your question to show the exact compilation command you used.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got fixed by updating my xcode command line tools