# std::regex_replace difference in behavior on different platforms

Tags: c++, regex, std

I'm experiencing two different behaviors using `std::regex_replace` between Apple clang 15.0.0 versus Windows's Visual Studio 2022 default MSVC compiler when on C++20. For the case of an empty pattern and empty replacement string, I get different outputs. On Mac, the replaced string is empty. On Windows, the string is the original text.

My questions are:

- In terms of ECMA style regex (if it makes any difference), which platform is behaving correctly?
- Does the C++ standard mention anything on the parameters passed into `std::regex_replace` and its behaviors?
- Do work arounds exist with `std::regex` to get consistent behaviors on both platforms without resorting to sanitizing inputs prior to calling the library?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
 
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    std::string text = "Excellent";
    std::string pattern = "";
    std::string replacement = "";
    std::string result;
    std::regex regexPattern(pattern, std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::icase);
    result = std::regex_replace(text, regexPattern, replacement);

    cout << "Result: " << result << endl;
}
```

On MacOS `g++ -std=C++20 -Wall Test.cpp` the output is an empty string:
`Result:`

On MSVC the output is the original text.
`Result: Excellent`

Comment: Looks like bug in clangs `libc++` with `libstdc++` works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/Y7nz5eTWG

Comment: Related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19774902/1387438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like MSVC is producing the correct output.

You're searching for an empty regex, which can't match anything (that is, it matches an empty string, which doesn't contain anything). You haven't passed the `format_no_copy` flag in your call to `regex_replace`, therefore (N4950, [re.alg.replace]/1):

> *Effects*: Constructs a `regex_iterator` object `i` as if by
> `regex_iterator<BidirectionalIterator, charT, traits> i(first, last, e, flags)`
> and uses `i` to enumerate through all of the matches `m` of type `match_results<BidirectionalIterator>`
> that occur within the sequence `[first, last)`. If no such matches are found and `!(flags & regex_- constants::format_no_copy)`, then calls
> `out = copy(first, last, out)`
> If any matches are found then, for each such match:
> — If `!(flags & regex_constants::format_no_copy)`, calls
> `out = copy(m.prefix().first, m.prefix().second, out)`
> — Then calls
> `out = m.format(out, fmt, flags)`
> for the first form of the function and
> `out = m.format(out, fmt, fmt + char_traits<charT>::length(fmt), flags)`
> for the second.
> Finally, if such a match is found and `!(flags & regex_constants::format_no_copy)`, calls
> `out = copy(last_m.suffix().first, last_m.suffix().second, out)`
> where `last_m` is a copy of the last match found. If `flags & regex_constants::format_first_only`
> is nonzero, then only the first match found is replaced.

As noted above, there is a `format_no_copy` flag you can pass that should produce empty output on any platform (but that may have undesirable side-effects--it'll produce empty output for any regex that doesn't match any part of the string you passed).

For what it's worth, with your original code gcc and clang on Fedora produce the same result as MSVC, so apparently at least a few other people agree that's the correct result. If you do pass the `format_no_copy` flag, both produce empty output (as expected).

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I'm a bit hesitant on calling this a bug on Apple's std implementation. Is this statement true in some standard "You're searching for an empty regex, which can't match anything." ?

Comment: @Miket25: Since you passed the ECmAScript flag, the standard is [ECMA-262](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-compilesubpattern), section 22.2, as modified in section [re.pattern] in the C++ standard, so tracking down all the details gets kind of ugly. The specific definition of an empty pattern is in section 22.2.2.3 of the ECMAScript standard. At least as far as I can see, [re.grammar] doesn't modify that part of the ECMAScript definition.