# Weird issue with boost 1.69.0 and openmpi 2.1.2

Tags: boost, openmpi

Can someone help me make sense of the following segfault 11 error?

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004425e0 in boost::system::error_category::equivalent(boost::system::error_code const&, int) const ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000000004425e0 in boost::system::error_category::equivalent(boost::system::error_code const&, int) const ()
#1  0x0000000000414a58 in _GLOBAL__sub_I_operations.cpp ()
#2  0x000000000047d40d in __libc_csu_init ()
#3  0x00002aaaab9b24d5 in __libc_start_main (main=0x414730 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffff9b38, init=0x47d3c0 <__libc_csu_init>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffff9b28) at ../csu/libc-start.c:225
#4  0x0000000000414a90 in _start ()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Segmentation fault with boost::filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469887/segmentation-fault-with-boostfilesystem)

Comment: Yes it was the -std flag I was missing for my Boost build.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something might be raising an error before the static data for eg Boost System had been initialized ¹.

The most likely culprit in such a case is global variables with non-trivial constructors.

If the constructors try to do something before start of `main` it may fall because the relevant library is not yet initialised.

¹ see "Static Initialization Order Fiasco"

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:
[Segmentation fault with boost::filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469887/segmentation-fault-with-boostfilesystem)

I didnt compile boost with the same flags as my application ... specifically -std=c++14.